# Spring supply Qualifier on injection inside third party class with no setters

Tags: java, spring

I am injecting a class B from another project into my class A in my project. Class B has an interface injected which has implementation C but I want to use implementation D from my project for that interface. Class B do not have setter for interface so I can not use setter injection. Please help how can I achieve this use case using spring.

Comment: How does class B choose the implementation C? Does class B accept an instance of implementation C in the constructor?

Comment: You say that class B has a C "injected"--how *exactly* is that done?

Comment: The interface is autowired via @autowired annotation in Class B. And Class C implements the interface.